# Model Associations in Rails has_one with class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, database-design, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to find an optimal way to model my database.
**Background:**

- I currently have two rails Models, one called `Environment` and the other called `StatusUpdate`.
- I have a program that sits on various servers and submits `StatusUpdates` for `Environments`. These updates contain four pieces of information about an environment.
- I have an index screen that shows me all `Environments`. (Modeled below)

  - **My aim is to show the user all information from the most recent status update about an environment.**
- I store the ten most recent `StatusUpdates` and anything > 10 is deleted upon receiving a new one.

**Basic index layout**
-- Environment1 --Status_Field_1--Status_Field_2--Status_Field_3--Status_Field_4--
-- Environment2 --Status_Field_1--Status_Field_2--Status_Field_3--Status_Field_4--
-- Environment3 --Status_Field_1--Status_Field_2--Status_Field_3--Status_Field_4--
-- Environment4 --Status_Field_1--Status_Field_2--Status_Field_3--Status_Field_4--

**Current Schema**

```
Environment(name):has_many StatusUpdates
StatusUpdate(field1, field2, field3, field4): belongs_to Environment
```

**Environments Controller**

```
def index
    @environments = Environment.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

I then render `@environments` using a partial.

**The Question**
The current schema seems appropriate, but I suspect I would have to make an extra call to the database in the EnvironmentsController during the index function. Do I change the `Environment` schema to include fields 1 - 4? Or is there a way to execute `Environment.paginate` while retrieving the most recent StatusUpdate from the database for each Environment?

H-man's recommendation sounds perfect, but I can't figure out why I am receiving an unexpected tLabel error in my model with the has_one association he recommended. For reference:

```
class Environment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many: status_updates
    has_one: current_status, -> { order: 'created_at DESC' }, class_name: 'StatusUpdate'
end
```

Rails 4.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Environment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :status_updates
  has_one :current_status, -> {order 'created_at DESC'}, class_name: 'StatusUpdate'
end
```

Then you can do this:

```
def index
  @environments = Environment.includes(:current_status).paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

This will eager-load the current status update for all environments in one go. I assume you're using Rails 4 since you didn't mention the version #. If you're using an older version of rails, use this instead:

```
  has_one :current_status, class_name: 'StatusUpdate', order: 'created_at DESC'
```

Comment: For the first code block, I noticed you had `def Environment ...` instead of `class Environment ...`, is there a purpose for this or just a typo? I suspect the latter, but I'm encountering an error and wanted to make sure =] Currently getting the error `unexpected tLABEL` and the code references the has_one Association in the model. `has_one :current_status, -> { order: 'created_at DESC' }, class_name: 'StatusUpdate'` Also, Rails 4.0.2

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should be `class Environment`. Fixed.

Comment: No worries! Though I put this in my model a few hours ago and carefully mulled through all my code. It's verbatim what you wrote, and I verified with Rails API. I'm still getting an unexpected tLabel error on the has_one association line. Any thoughts? Do I need some sort of migration?

Comment: Ah.. another typo :( should be: ```has_one :current_status, -> {order 'created_at DESC'}, class_name: 'StatusUpdate'```

Comment: Ha! Colon gets me every time ;) Thanks, this is perfect! Rails is so cool!